# Converting numeric dates into Hours since format

Tags: r, time

I'm having problems converting dates into an "hours since" format, I don't think I need to apply some of the more complex methods of date manipulation, but I might be wrong, I was hoping someone might know a good solution?

The data I have is in a table format, which I read in from a text file. A 3 line example of the 5,000+ rows of data is;

```
date1 <- matrix(c(2007,2007,2007, 12,12,12,1,2,3,0.365,0.096,-0.416),nrow=3)
```

Which prints out as:

```
date1
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,] 2007    12    1  0.365
[2,] 2007    12    2  0.096
[3,] 2007    12    3 -0.416
```

The first column is the year, the second the month, and third the day. The value in the 4th column is an index value relevant to my study.

The data I would like to match the index value is in a slightly odd format, of hours since "1800-01-01"

```
ftime <- c(1822548, 1822572, 1822596)
```

ftime can be printed as just a date, via the following function.

```
as.Date(ftime/24,"1800-01-01")
[1] "2007-12-01" "2007-12-02" "2007-12-03"
```

My code all uses the numeric values in ftime to match data, but I cannot seem to work out how to format the new data (data1) into the same.

I have the feeling it should be a simple solution, but cannot seem to get it to work.

Help is always greatly appreciated!

Comment: I am not sure whether you're having difficulties getting the date in `date1` into a string like in `ftime` or the other way around?

Comment: I was after date1 in the format of ftime, sorry for not being clear!

Comment: Is the provided answer what you were looking for? If so could you please accept the answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `difftime` function, if I got what you want:

```
    #setting the origin
    myorigin<-as.Date("1800-01-01")
    #converting date1 to Date objects
    myDates<-as.Date(do.call(function(...) paste(...,sep="-"),as.data.frame(date1[,1:3])))
    #get the results
    difftime(myDates,myorigin,units="hour")
    #Time differences in hours
    #[1] 1822536 1822560 1822584
```